# Fastest way to populate a column from another table in R?

Tags: r

I have 2 tables and I need to create a new column "Number" where it populates it with the col2 respective value. My data contains couple of hundreds of rows and I used for loop to populate it but it takes lots of time is there a faster way?

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 55 |
| B | 77 |
| C | 80 |
| D | 9 |

| Letter | Number |
| --- | --- |
| A |  |
| B |  |
| C |  |
| D |  |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `match`.

```
transform(df2, Number=df1[match(Letter, df1$Col1), ]$Col2)
#   Letter Number
# 1      A     55
# 2      B     77
# 3      C     80
# 4      D      9
```

---

*Data:*

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), Col2 = c(55L, 77L, 
80L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df2 <- structure(list(Letter = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), Number = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```